# I receive this attribute error "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'type_of_payment'" I am fairly new to python so I apologize if dumb

Tags: python

These are the definitions

```
Payment = Enum('Payment', ['food', 'consulting', 'honoraria', 'travel', 'services', 'gift', 'education','entertainment', 'grant', 'space_rental', 'royalties', 'investment', 'charity'])
# interp. types/natures of payments or transactions 
#examples are redundant for enumerations


GeneralPaymentTypeDistribution = NamedTuple ('GeneralPaymentTypeDistribution', [('total_amount', float), # in range[0, ...) 
                                              ('type_of_payment', Payment), 
                                              ('degree', str)]) 
 # interp. general information about a payment with the total amount, type of payment, and type of medical doctor
```

this is the code. It takes the compound list and adds the amount to the corresponding sum and adds a value to counter to know how many additions have been done. These to values are then sent to another average function where they are divided. However I keep on receiving an error about float for type_of_payment when that var is an enumeration. I understand that the code may be inefficient but it should still work??

```
def average_list(avg: List[GeneralPaymentTypeDistribution]) -> List[float]: 
"""
returns a list containing averages of each of the transaction types 
"""
#return [] #stub
# template from List[GeneralPaymentTypeDistribution]
# acc contains the result so far
acc = [] # type: List[only_do] 
sum_1 = 0  
sum_2 = 0 
sum_3 = 0 
sum_4 = 0 
sum_5 = 0  
sum_6 = 0 
sum_7 = 0 
sum_8 = 0 
sum_9 = 0 
sum_10 = 0   
sum_11 = 0 
sum_12 = 0
counter_1 = 0 
counter_2 = 0
counter_3 = 0
counter_4 = 0
counter_5 = 0
counter_6 = 0
counter_7 = 0
counter_8 = 0
counter_9 = 0
counter_10 = 0 
counter_11 =0 
counter_12 = 0
for a in avg:
    if a.type_of_payment == Payment.food:
        sum_1 = sum_1 + a.total_amount 
        counter_1 = counter_2 + 1 
    elif a.type_of_payment == Payment.consulting:
        sum_2 = sum_2 + a.total_amount
        counter_2 = counter_2 + 1 
    elif a.type_of_payment == Payment.honoraria:
        sum_3 = sum_3 + a.total_amount
        counter_3 = counter_3 + 1 
    elif a.type_of_payment == Payment.travel:
        sum_4 = sum_4 + a.total_amount
        counter_4 = counter_4 + 1 
    elif a.type_of_payment == Payment.services:
        sum_5 = sum_5 + a.total_amount 
        counter_5 = counter_5 + 1 
    elif a.type_of_payment == Payment.gift:
        sum_6 = sum_6 + a.total_amount
        counter_6 = counter_6 + 1 
    elif a.type_of_payment == Payment.education : 
        sum_7 = sum_7 + a.total_amount 
        counter_7 = counter_7 + 1  
    elif a.type_of_payment == Payment.entertainment : 
        sum_7 = sum_7 + a.total_amount
        counter_7 = counter_7 + 1 
    elif a.type_of_payment == Payment.grant :
        sum_8 = sum_8 + a.total_amount 
        counter_8 = counter_8 + 1 
    elif a.type_of_payment == Payment.space_rental:
        sum_9 = sum_9 + a.total_amount
        counter_9 = counter_9 + 1 
    elif a.type_of_payment == Payment.royalties :
        sum_10 = sum_10 + a.total_amount
        counter_10 = counter_10 + 1 
    elif a.type_of_payment == Payment.investment :
        sum_11 = sum_11 + a.total_amount
        counter_11 = counter_11 + 1 
    elif a.type_of_payment == Payment.charity :
        sum_12 = sum_12 + a.total_amount
        counter_12 = counter_12 + 1
return acc.append([average_calculation(sum_1,counter_1), 
                  average_calculation(sum_2,counter_2), 
                  average_calculation(sum_3,counter_3), 
                  average_calculation(sum_4,counter_4), 
                  average_calculation(sum_5,counter_5), 
                  average_calculation(sum_6,counter_6), 
                  average_calculation(sum_7,counter_7), 
                  average_calculation(sum_8,counter_8),
                  average_calculation(sum_9,counter_9), 
                  average_calculation(sum_10,counter_10), 
                  average_calculation(sum_11,counter_11), 
                  average_calculation(sum_12,counter_12)])

 @typecheck 
 def average_calculation(sum0: float, counter: int) -> float:  
"""
return average by dividing the sum by the number of instances 
"""
# return 0 #stub
# template from GeneralPaymentTypeDistribution 
if counter == 0: 
    return 0 
else:
    return sum0/counter
```

Here is the error message

[AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'type_of_payment'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTFxi.png)

Comment: Your code is misformatted. Please format it properly.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you do `average_list(data)` instead of `average_list([data])` (your function expects a list of namedtuples but you pass single namedtuple instead).